# Where can I manage all my missions?

Tags: far-cry-4

I can't find an overview with all my missions (open/done).

How can I see which missions are for the main story and which one to level up?

How can I choose another mission?

Answer (score -2):

you can't replay a mission in far cry 4. you can neither see witch mission is a main mission.